# Notification when an object is released by ARC System

Tags: ios, notifications, automatic-ref-counting, mpmovieplayercontroller, dealloc

I am converting my Huge project to ARC, though success fully converted and I am using it but there are some lines of code still there in dealloc which needs to be called anyway.
Example I was stopping and releasing the MPMoviePlayerController properly when dealloc used to call before ARC or any other notifications needs to be unregistered in dealloc.

Now the problem is I am using dealloc (without [super dealloc]) but it's not getting called, is there any tweak by which I can get the call to dealloc so that I dont have to change the bulk of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dealloc` normally gets called in an ARC environment.  You can verify it for yourself by creating a local variable pointing to a simple object that has a NSLog in its `dealloc` and then letting it fall out of scope.

You might want to use Instruments to trace what's holding onto your object.

Comment: Oh sorry I got it its being retained by super view thanks!! Working now !!